# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects in multithreading

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to accelerate an OPENCV video processing with multiprocessing, but I get an exception in the queue.

The class pipeline, it takes and image and some Kalman filter trackers, and returns an image with the tracked cars, peds,..etc.

It has all the calculations done there.

Error:

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Code:

```
class DummyTask:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def ready(self):
        return True
    def get(self):
        return self.data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_name = '2016-11-18_07-30-01.h264'

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)

    det = detector.CarDetector()
    car_tracker = Sort_Algorithm.Sort()
    ped_tracker = Sort_Algorithm.Sort()
    df_region, df_line = load_filter()
    threadn = cv2.getNumberOfCPUs()
    pool = Pool(processes = 2)
    pending = Queue()
    threaded_mode = True

    while True:
        while pending.qsize() > 0:
            res = pending.get()
            cv2.imshow('video ', res)

        if  pending.qsize() < 2:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if threaded_mode:
                t1 = time.time()
                H = [-2.01134074616, -16.6502442427, -1314.05715739, -3.35391526592, -22.3546973012, 2683.63584335,
                     -0.00130731963137, -0.0396207582264, 1]
                matrix = np.reshape(H, (3, 3))
                dst = cv2.warpPerspective(frame.copy(), matrix, (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]))
                task = pool.apply_async(pipeline, (frame.copy(),car_tracker, ped_tracker,df_region, df_line, det, dst, matrix))

                cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
            else:
                task = DummyTask(pipeline,(frame.copy(),car_tracker, ped_tracker,df_region, df_line, det, dst, matrix))

            pending.put(task)
        ch = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == ord(' '):
            threaded_mode = not threaded_mode
        if ch == 27:
            break
```

Comment: The error message you're getting seems somewhat self-explanatory to me. One of the objects you're trying to pass to another process contains a lock, and that means it can't be passed successfully. It's not obvious which object is causing the problem, but it's got to be one of `car_tracker, ped_tracker,df_region, df_line, det, dst`. If those are things you control, you may need modify their code. If not, you may need to write some code to create the objects you need in the worker processes instead of in the main process.

Comment: Can you show an example of modifing the code ?

Comment: I can't modify the code for those objects you're passing because you don't show any of it in your question. Figure out where the Lock is being created, and you might be able to do something about it.

Comment: @Blckknght How can I know which one has a lock ?

Comment: @Blckknght I have det which uses tensorflow.. any idea how to fix it